# Blowup of $C\times D$ has finite $(-1)$-curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267649/infinitely-many-exceptional-curves-on-ruled-surfaces) and in the proof of the fact

> If $C$, $D$ are smooth curves and  $g(C) \geq 1$, then any blow-up of $C \times D$ contains at most *finitely many* $(-1)$-curves.

Here we take the projection $p:S\to C$, where $\pi:S\to C\times D$ is a blow-up. Then the proof noted that no rational curve in $S$ can dominate $C$ which I understand. But I don't understand why the next step holds, that is, why does this mean that the $(-1)$-curves are contained in reducible fibers of $p$ and why are there only finitely many of them?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a map of smooth projective curves is surjective or constant, a $(-1)$-curve must map to a point in $C$, so every $(-1)$-curve is contained in a fiber of $p$. On the other hand, $\pi$ is the blowup of $C\times D$ in a finite set of points $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$, and every fiber of $p$ over a point $c\in C$ which is not the projection of an $x_i$ is the same as the fiber of $C\times D\to C$ over that point. So only finitely many fibers can contain a $(-1)$-curve, and as each fiber has finitely many irreducible components, there can only be finitely many $(-1)$ curves in a given fiber, giving finitely many $(-1)$-curves in $S$.

The bit about reducible fibers comes from calculating the fibers of $\pi$. If $\pi: X'\to X$ is the blowup of a smooth surface in a point $x$, then the total transform of any curve $Z\subset X$ is given by $\widetilde{Z}+\mu_x(Z)E$, where $\widetilde{-}$ is the strict  transform, $\mu_x(Z)$ is the multiplicity of $Z$ at $x$, and $E$ is the exceptional divisor. In particular, writing $\pi$ as a composition of finitely many blowups of single points, you can conclude that the fiber over $c$ has $\#\{x_i\mid x_i\mapsto c\}+1$ irreducible components - one which is the strict transform of the original fiber, the rest of which will be $(-1)$-curves.